# Windows 10 Windows Update not working (no error details)

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

My windows update is constantly failing with the following error:

> There were problems installing some updates, but we'll try again later. If you keep seeing this and want to search the web or contact support for information, this may help:

After 'this might help' there is just blank space and the Retry button. Pressing retry just does a small animation and the error is back again.

[image]

Looking at the windows update I can see that package KB3119142 has failed (although it was successfully installed several times). I've seen on the internet that this update causes issues and I've tried the suggestions on how to fix it (by going to Programs & Features and repairing the installation). But still it did not help.

[image]

I've tried every possible solution that I could find on internet:

1. Running sfc /scannow
2. Running Microsoft WindowsUpdateDiagnostic.diagcab tool
3. Running Microsoft ResetWUEng.cmd
4. Trying several various online solutions with various restarts of services, deleting some files etc.

Nothing helped. 
Here is the excerpt of the latest try in the WindowsUpdate.log (generated via Powershell):

```
2016.02.08 22:08:38.1438780 8904  8928  ComApi          * START *   Init Search ClientId = NULL
2016.02.08 22:08:38.1438819 8904  8928  ComApi          * START *   Search ClientId = NULL
2016.02.08 22:08:38.1476859 104   1760  Agent           * START * Queueing Finding updates [CallerId = <<PROCESS>>: DllHost.exe  Id = 5]
2016.02.08 22:08:38.1476937 104   1760  Agent           Added service 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 to sequential scan list
2016.02.08 22:08:38.1479222 8904  8928  ComApi          Search ClientId = NULL
2016.02.08 22:08:38.4485033 104   5996  ProtocolTalker  PTInfo: syncing with server using normal query
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6122826 104   5996  ProtocolTalker  SyncUpdates round trips: 22
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6159627 104   5996  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C18&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_B5
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6159636 104   5996  Driver          Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6160245 104   5996  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C18}
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6160705 104   5996  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0100&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_09
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6160708 104   5996  Driver          Status: 0x180000a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6160783 104   5996  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0100}
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6161095 104   5996  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C2D&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_05
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6161095 104   5996  Driver          Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6161314 104   5996  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C2D}
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6161722 104   5996  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C26&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_05
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6161722 104   5996  Driver          Status: 0x180000a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6161842 104   5996  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C26}
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6162098 104   5996  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0101&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_09
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6162101 104   5996  Driver          Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6162371 104   5996  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0101}
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6162545 104   5996  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C44&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_05
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6162548 104   5996  Driver          Status: 0x180000a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6162899 104   5996  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C44}
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6162965 104   5996  Driver          Matched driver to device ACPI\VEN_INT&DEV_3F0D
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6162965 104   5996  Driver          Status: 0x41802000, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6163403 104   5996  Driver          DrvUtil: {ACPI\INT3F0D}
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6163542 104   5996  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C22&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_05
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6163545 104   5996  Driver          Status: 0x1802000, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6163935 104   5996  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C22}
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6164247 104   5996  Driver          Matched driver to device USB\VID_0B05&PID_179C&REV_0001
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6164250 104   5996  Driver          Status: 00000000, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6164547 104   5996  Driver          DrvUtil: {usb\vid_0b05&pid_179c}
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6164625 104   5996  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C1C&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_B5
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6164628 104   5996  Driver          Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6165076 104   5996  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C1C}
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6165301 104   5996  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C1E&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_B5
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6165304 104   5996  Driver          Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6165604 104   5996  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C1E}
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6165703 104   5996  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C10&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_B5
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6165706 104   5996  Driver          Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6166129 104   5996  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C10}
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6166408 104   5996  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_13C2&SUBSYS_13C210DE&REV_A1
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6166408 104   5996  Driver          Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6166661 104   5996  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_13C2}
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6166751 104   5996  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&SUBSYS_84321043&REV_06
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6166754 104   5996  Driver          Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6167183 104   5996  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&SUBSYS_84321043&REV_06}
2016.02.08 22:08:39.6167360 104   5996  Driver          DrvUtil: {usbprint\hewlett-packardhp_la5a02}
2016.02.08 22:08:41.1568919 104   5996  ProtocolTalker  ServiceId = {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77}, Server URL = https://fe2.update.microsoft.com/v6/ClientWebService/client.asmx
2016.02.08 22:08:41.1568934 104   5996  ProtocolTalker  OK to reuse existing configuration
2016.02.08 22:08:41.1568958 104   5996  ProtocolTalker  Existing cookie is valid, just use it
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6673071 104   5996  Agent           Added update B176D5A0-9EFC-404F-BEE7-BCD6CAE6226B.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6673113 104   5996  Agent           Added update 4A2305D9-E940-48E6-9CE4-D11964F7DC2F.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6673143 104   5996  Agent           Added update 9388C4AD-970E-4D1E-BDF6-20C206192BB1.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6673173 104   5996  Agent           Added update B69DEC14-F236-48A1-AA30-30A5293A54CB.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6673203 104   5996  Agent           Added update DD696945-7B9D-41D4-A8DC-7589DC414CC6.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6673236 104   5996  Agent           Added update 26CCDB78-D852-4EDD-91CF-76956D5EEE63.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6673263 104   5996  Agent           Added update 83F87564-25D9-4044-9A89-781714992321.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6673290 104   5996  Agent           Added update 077DA652-E8B5-4E59-BBB4-79AE56991BF0.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6673407 104   5996  Agent           Added update E80BB0B5-277A-4208-9296-7F16488E409B.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6673437 104   5996  Agent           Added update AF090FC3-1779-4EC8-8C63-8A84C0B3E5FB.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6673467 104   5996  Agent           Added update F8E06312-3A36-4868-8CE5-A6BEFF34A294.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6673494 104   5996  Agent           Added update 2B11F691-8DB6-4985-9B7C-C0481E7556E3.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6673527 104   5996  Agent           Added update EDE0C184-119B-442F-A6F7-6B014FD64727.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6673558 104   5996  Agent           Added update 19978BC2-2F56-48D0-92A9-C5CA7B04F121.201 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6673585 104   5996  Agent           Added update C38BEDE9-86AD-4337-81A4-16E6914980DB.208 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6675929 104   5996  Agent           Found 15 updates and 21 categories in search; evaluated appl. rules of 757 out of 1240 deployed entities
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6795172 104   5996  Agent           * END * Finding updates CallerId = Device Driver Retrieval Client  Id = 3
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6900431 104   1764  ComApi          *RESUMED* Search ClientId = Device Driver Retrieval Client
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6918584 104   8992  Agent           * END * Queueing Finding updates [CallerId = <<PROCESS>>: DllHost.exe  Id = 5]
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6928935 104   8992  Agent           * START * Finding updates CallerId = <<PROCESS>>: DllHost.exe  Id = 5
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6928944 104   8992  Agent           Online = Yes; Ignore download priority = No
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6928950 104   8992  Agent           Criteria = ( IsInstalled = 0 and IsHidden = 0 )""
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6928983 104   8992  Agent           ServiceID = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} Third party service
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6928986 104   8992  Agent           Search Scope = {Machine}
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6929010 104   8992  Agent           Caller SID for Applicability: S-1-5-18
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6929019 104   8992  Agent           RegisterService is set
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6943437 104   8992  Misc            Got 9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77 redir SecondaryServiceAuth URL: 7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d""
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6974711 104   1764  ComApi          Updates found = 15
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6974717 104   1764  ComApi          * END *   Search ClientId = Device Driver Retrieval Client
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6978389 104   1548  ComApi          ISusInternal:: DisconnectCall failed, hr=8024000C
2016.02.08 22:08:41.6994860 104   8992  Misc            Got 7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D redir Client/Server URL: https://fe2.update.microsoft.com/v6/ClientWebService/client.asmx""
2016.02.08 22:08:42.0066264 104   8992  ProtocolTalker  ServiceId = {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D}, Server URL = https://fe2.update.microsoft.com/v6/ClientWebService/client.asmx
2016.02.08 22:08:42.0066345 104   8992  ProtocolTalker  OK to reuse existing configuration
2016.02.08 22:08:42.0066369 104   8992  ProtocolTalker  Existing cookie is valid, just use it
2016.02.08 22:08:42.9943524 104   8992  WebServices     Auto proxy settings for this web service call.
2016.02.08 22:08:49.8519573 104   8992  ProtocolTalker  PTInfo: syncing with server using normal query
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0387275 104   8992  ProtocolTalker  SyncUpdates round trips: 2
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0472755 104   8992  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C18&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_B5
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0472761 104   8992  Driver          Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0473455 104   8992  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C18}
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0473899 104   8992  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0100&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_09
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0473902 104   8992  Driver          Status: 0x180000a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0473977 104   8992  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0100}
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0474277 104   8992  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C2D&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_05
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0474280 104   8992  Driver          Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0474494 104   8992  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C2D}
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0474890 104   8992  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C26&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_05
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0474890 104   8992  Driver          Status: 0x180000a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0475007 104   8992  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C26}
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0475256 104   8992  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0101&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_09
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0475256 104   8992  Driver          Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0475520 104   8992  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0101}
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0475688 104   8992  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C44&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_05
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0475691 104   8992  Driver          Status: 0x180000a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0476033 104   8992  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C44}
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0476097 104   8992  Driver          Matched driver to device ACPI\VEN_INT&DEV_3F0D
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0476100 104   8992  Driver          Status: 0x41802000, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0476526 104   8992  Driver          DrvUtil: {ACPI\INT3F0D}
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0476658 104   8992  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C22&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_05
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0476661 104   8992  Driver          Status: 0x1802000, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0477039 104   8992  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C22}
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0477342 104   8992  Driver          Matched driver to device USB\VID_0B05&PID_179C&REV_0001
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0477345 104   8992  Driver          Status: 00000000, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0477634 104   8992  Driver          DrvUtil: {usb\vid_0b05&pid_179c}
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0477709 104   8992  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C1C&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_B5
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0477712 104   8992  Driver          Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0478147 104   8992  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C1C}
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0478366 104   8992  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C1E&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_B5
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0478366 104   8992  Driver          Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0478657 104   8992  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C1E}
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0478756 104   8992  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C10&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_B5
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0478759 104   8992  Driver          Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0479171 104   8992  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C10}
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0479498 104   8992  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_13C2&SUBSYS_13C210DE&REV_A1
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0479501 104   8992  Driver          Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0479921 104   8992  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_13C2}
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0480020 104   8992  Driver          Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&SUBSYS_84321043&REV_06
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0480020 104   8992  Driver          Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0480698 104   8992  Driver          DrvUtil: {PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&SUBSYS_84321043&REV_06}
2016.02.08 22:08:51.0480867 104   8992  Driver          DrvUtil: {usbprint\hewlett-packardhp_la5a02}
2016.02.08 22:08:52.6314830 104   8992  ProtocolTalker  ServiceId = {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D}, Server URL = https://fe2.update.microsoft.com/v6/ClientWebService/client.asmx
2016.02.08 22:08:52.6314848 104   8992  ProtocolTalker  OK to reuse existing configuration
2016.02.08 22:08:52.6314878 104   8992  ProtocolTalker  Existing cookie is valid, just use it
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8183480 104   8992  Agent           Update 5AF4FF91-E9A7-45B3-841F-AE886BB3C658.201 is pruned out due to potential supersedence
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8183543 104   8992  Agent           Added update B176D5A0-9EFC-404F-BEE7-BCD6CAE6226B.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8183558 104   8992  Agent           Update 81E92824-528F-4583-B074-406D9ED8701B.200 is pruned out due to potential supersedence
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8183585 104   8992  Agent           Added update 4A2305D9-E940-48E6-9CE4-D11964F7DC2F.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8183612 104   8992  Agent           Added update 9388C4AD-970E-4D1E-BDF6-20C206192BB1.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8183639 104   8992  Agent           Added update B69DEC14-F236-48A1-AA30-30A5293A54CB.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8183663 104   8992  Agent           Added update DD696945-7B9D-41D4-A8DC-7589DC414CC6.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8183685 104   8992  Agent           Added update 26CCDB78-D852-4EDD-91CF-76956D5EEE63.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8183712 104   8992  Agent           Added update 83F87564-25D9-4044-9A89-781714992321.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8183736 104   8992  Agent           Added update 077DA652-E8B5-4E59-BBB4-79AE56991BF0.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8183817 104   8992  Agent           Added update E80BB0B5-277A-4208-9296-7F16488E409B.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8183844 104   8992  Agent           Added update AF090FC3-1779-4EC8-8C63-8A84C0B3E5FB.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8183868 104   8992  Agent           Added update F8E06312-3A36-4868-8CE5-A6BEFF34A294.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8183889 104   8992  Agent           Added update 2B11F691-8DB6-4985-9B7C-C0481E7556E3.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8183904 104   8992  Agent           Update 95B42BE3-50BA-4AD2-908B-AF3F10304827.201 is pruned out due to potential supersedence
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8183928 104   8992  Agent           Added update EDE0C184-119B-442F-A6F7-6B014FD64727.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8183952 104   8992  Agent           Added update 547D2F41-089B-448F-9265-79579EC92F80.200 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8183997 104   8992  Agent           Added update 077DB01E-86F1-445A-BEF8-4B5DE97C899E.204 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8184021 104   8992  Agent           Added update 19978BC2-2F56-48D0-92A9-C5CA7B04F121.201 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8184066 104   8992  Agent           Added update C38BEDE9-86AD-4337-81A4-16E6914980DB.208 to search result
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8184075 104   8992  Agent           Found 17 updates and 89 categories in search; evaluated appl. rules of 1442 out of 2019 deployed entities
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8287437 104   8992  Agent           * END * Finding updates CallerId = <<PROCESS>>: DllHost.exe  Id = 5
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8385699 8904  8924  ComApi          *RESUMED* Search ClientId = NULL
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8452030 8904  8924  ComApi          Updates found = 17
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8452036 8904  8924  ComApi          * END *   Search ClientId = NULL
2016.02.08 22:08:52.8473686 8904  8928  ComApi          ISusInternal:: DisconnectCall failed, hr=8024000C
2016.02.08 22:09:35.1743632 104   3556  Shared          UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 2.
```

From the log I would say that there are quite a few updates to be installed. But no information why it is failing. The event logs are all normal, there are no error or warnings of any kind.

Comment: I did not mention it in the post but I did run the DISM tool together with sfc  and although it fixed some errors the problem still remained.

Comment: @Moab I've just downloaded and used the tool to install the updates. Seems to work great.Thanks for the tip - please post an answer so that I can upvote it and mark it as answer - you deserve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution for Windows 10 updates is using a 3rd party software to install and hide updates.

It installs nothing, it is portable, it allows you to hide any update including drivers. This Software makes no changes to the normal windows update or your system (except for the updates you allow it to install) but does use the Windows update service, once you have hidden your updates and installed others you want, be sure to go into Windows Services and stop the Windows update service and then set it to disabled, or it will install the updates you hid using the other software.

So keep the windows update service disabled, the minitool will start it automatically when you run it, then disable it again when done using the minitool.

[Here is the download link](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/3E95/kvd9WCbUq) for the minitool

[Originally found it here](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/windows-update-minitool.380535/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer so I am posting it here so that it might help some other pool soul who got trapped by the hideous and ugly monster that is Windows 10.
Although everyone claims it is not possible to control Windows Update there is a Microsoft tool which can be used to disable updates called 'Show or hide updates'.
The tool can be found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930
The tool is meant to be used to prevent installation of faulty drivers and it seems that this is what is happening on my side.

I ran the tool and disabled the HP driver for my printer and the update now says that my device is up to date.

[image]

Curiously enough there are several other updates that I can also disable but even though they appear in the list of updates in the 'Show or hide updates' tool the Windows Update is claiming that there are no updates.

[image]

Currently I have no idea why the rest of the update will not install.

Comment: You can update all of those by going to Nvidia's or Intel's website directly.  the drivers on Windows Update are not current, you shouldn't use Windows Update, to keep device drivers updated.

Comment: That Windows tool only delays the install of that driver, it will eventually try to reinstall it at a later date

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. I will try to install drivers via manufacturers sites.

Comment: Hmm seems like Intel has no drivers for Windows 10. Great

Comment: When you remove your rant I will reverse my vote.  Most of those Intel drivers are not required for the device to function by the way, you already have, the current Nvidia driver installed more the likely

Answer (score 0):

Open (Desktop) Control Panel, go to Programs & Features, select the VC++ 2012 Runtime entries, click on Modifiy and select repair.

[image]

After this install the VC++ Update again and should work.

Comment: I already did that but the problem with the update still remained.

Comment: ok, use the 3rd party tool, which I also use on my test system